# Is there any distributed file system which runs on Windows except Hadoop?

Tags: windows, hadoop, microsoft-distributed-file-system, hdfs

I'm desperate to find any DFS which supports Windows. The only such DFS is Hadoop HDFS but it's very hard to deploy it other big number of Windows machines because it requires Cygwin + SSH.

Almost all DFS systems work only on Linux and only one (HDFS) runs on Windows.

I would be very grateful if somebody will be able to point me to other DFS with Windows support.

From DFS I need ability to load balance files across DFS nodes, compression and multi language API to work with DFS (I don't need to mount DFS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [DFS from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479%28WS.10%29.aspx) itself, it's in Windows Server (if it's good or bad I don't know)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You might want to check out [CloudIQ Storage](http://www.appistry.com) from Appistry.</strike>
(They have closed shop.)

It allows you to take the drives in commodity based machines (linux or windows) and have them appear as a single namespace accessible via a REST based API.  When you write files to the system, you can define the number of copies you want saved.  So if you had 5 machines in your distributed system, you could specify that a file be saved on 2 or 3 (or N) machines for redundancy.  If a machine/hard drive crashes, its not an issue, because other machines hold copies of those files.

Check out the Downloads and Community links for a trial version as well as documentation.

Comment: Thanks, very good solution and it feets my needs perfectly, but it isn't free or open source so I wont be able to use it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

GPFS is a worthy consideration. It is IBM proprietary, but does have very good scalability, is a full-fledged network file system, and has decent Windows support. NTFS ACLs are preserved, though mapping them to NFSv4 ACLs, which works quite well (so long as you don't shoot your foot off trying to use POSIX permissions as well; chmod will blow away your NFSv4 ACLs.)

Lustre is worth a mention, but Windows support is generally considered very poor and green.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has something like Azure, but I have not learned more about their solution.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenAFS](http://www.openafs.org/) is another DFS solution that runs on Windows.